# Do automatically generated notifications from deposit protection schemes' own computer systems adequately fulfill landlords statutory obligations?

Tags: england-and-wales, landlord, tenant, tenancy-rules, deposit

***Note: please provide citations on the issue to substantiate any answers.***

Under the housing act 2004 the landlord must furnish the tenant with information about their deposits protection within 30 days. This statutory obligation to the tenant seems to rest on the landlord, not the protection scheme which they might choose to use. If the scheme automatically emails the tenant information about their deposit reference is the landlord still required to serve such information upon the tenant themselves, under statute?

Answer (score 2):

### If they provide the required information within the required time

The “landlord … must give the tenant” does not imply that the service must be done personally. So long as the landlords actions cause the notice to be with the tenant, they have complied with the Act.

Comment: Can you cite some legal basis for this answer? Is there any case law supporting it, for example?

Comment: @JosephP. It’s a simple application of agency law - you can get people to do things for you.